# Python remove one of two duplicates (next to each other) in a list

Tags: python, list, duplicates, set

I have a list

```
A= [1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,4,7]
```

I want to only keep one `3` and `4` if they are next to another identical one.

Thus A should become

```
A= [1,2,3,4,5,6,4,7]
```

I tried to use `set`

```
set[A]

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

But it removed the last `4` that I want to keep. It seems I should loop through the list and compare i and i+1. Wondering any faster and smarter way exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
[A[i] for i in range(len(A)) if (i==0) or A[i] != A[i-1]]
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7]
```

The logic is to iterate through each index in the list and keep the number if either of the following conditions hold:

- `i==0` (the first element)
- `A[i] != A[i-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
A = [1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,4,7]
newlist = []
newlist.append(A[0])
for i, element in enumerate(A):
    if i > 0 and A[i - 1] != element:
        newlist.append(element)
```

Here, we loop through the list and check that every element is not equal to the element before it. It will return

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7]
```